# JAXB and Inheritance

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, unmarshalling

I have this xsd :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/XsdMath2" 
        xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/XsdMath2" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified">


    <complexType name="Utilisateur">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="tns:TraitementDTO">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="nomUtilisateur" type="string"></element>
                    <element name="passUtilisateur" type="string"></element>
                </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>

 <complexType name="TraitementDTO">
        <sequence>
            <element name="CodeTraitement" type="int"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>


    <element name="Create" type="tns:TraitementDTO"></element>
</schema>
```

I would like to know data on my class "Utilisateur" but with my xml :

```
 <Create xmlns="http://www.example.org/XsdMath2">
       <TraitementDTO>
          <CodeTraitement>0</CodeTraitement>
            <Utilisateur>
               <nomUtilisateur>nomok</nomUtilisateur>
               <passUtilisateur>passok</passUtilisateur>
             </Utilisateur>
       </TraitementDTO>
    </Create>
```

I can't make (instanceof) my class "TraitementDTO" or i can't use function with my class "Utilisateur", or Cast. but it's not working.
my code java :

```
 StringReader sr = new StringReader(this.message);
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("ActionMathML");
    Unmarshaller decodeur = context.createUnmarshaller();
     msgObject = decodeur.unmarshal(sr);  

         System.out.println(" action" + msgObject);

     if (msgObject instanceof TraitementDTO)
    {
         System.out.println(" action");
    }
```

How I can take my Data  because i try some solutions but it's not working. My Xsd is correct to retrieve my data ?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML does not match your XML Schema.  If you populate your object model and then marshal it you will see what the XML is supposed to look like.

### Marshal Example

**MarshalDemo**

```
package ActionMathML;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class MarshalDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("ActionMathML");

        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();

        Utilisateur utilisateur = objectFactory.createUtilisateur();
        utilisateur.setCodeTraitement(0);
        utilisateur.setNomUtilisateur("nomok");
        utilisateur.setPassUtilisateur("passok");

        JAXBElement<TraitementDTO> jaxbElement = objectFactory.createCreate(utilisateur);

        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is what the XML should look like based on your XML schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Create xmlns="http://www.example.org/XsdMath2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Utilisateur">
    <CodeTraitement>0</CodeTraitement>
    <nomUtilisateur>nomok</nomUtilisateur>
    <passUtilisateur>passok</passUtilisateur>
</Create>
```

### Unmarshal Example

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Create xmlns="http://www.example.org/XsdMath2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Utilisateur">
    <CodeTraitement>0</CodeTraitement>
    <nomUtilisateur>nomok</nomUtilisateur>
    <passUtilisateur>passok</passUtilisateur>
</Create>
```

**UnmarshalDemo**

```
package ActionMathML;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class UnmarshalDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("ActionMathML");

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/ActionMathML/input.xml");
        JAXBElement<TraitementDTO> jaxbElement = (JAXBElement<TraitementDTO>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        TraitementDTO traitementDTO = jaxbElement.getValue();
        System.out.println(traitementDTO.getCodeTraitement());

        if(traitementDTO instanceof Utilisateur) {
            Utilisateur utilisateur = (Utilisateur) traitementDTO;
            System.out.println(utilisateur.getNomUtilisateur());
            System.out.println(utilisateur.getPassUtilisateur());
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
0
nomok
passok
```

### For More Information

I have written more about JAXB and inheritance on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

Comment: ah ? how I can have a correct xml so , the problem concern the tag " </TraitementDTO>" ?

Comment: @user3557873 - I have updated my answer to show you what the XML should look like.  Note in your XML Schema there is no `TraitementDTO` or `Utilisateur` elements.

Comment: ok , but you have retrieve data for the TraitementDTO's class but i can't catch Data for my class "Utilisateur" ? it's impossible ?

Comment: @Hann - I have updated my answer to show the info from the `Utilisateur` class.  Note the value of the `xsi:type` attribute on the `Create` element that specifies that the type is `Utilisateur`.

Comment: okok ths so much , but The Xml is specific for Utilisateur's Class but this Xml is not an instance of Utilisateur , but how to find values of "nomUtilisateur" and "passUtilisateur" on the unmarshall ? 
 Sorry i'm novice on xsd.

Comment: @Hann - I have updated my answer further hopefully that helps.

Comment: You are so wonderfull , it's working , thank so muchhhhhh.  you have an expert on JAxb :) . thanks Blaise

Comment: I Need information about the Tag <create> , It's not a class , I can Identify by a unmarchaller ? or a search about a String Xml

Comment: @Hann - The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html